# RecyclerView Adapter cannot work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Question is simple, I used recyclerview adapter and set at mainactivity.A pplication started but adapter field just white blank. No error. When I was debugging, I saw Adapter constructor method work but onBindViewHolder didn't work.

MainActivity OnCreate Method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    productList = new ArrayList<>();
    productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this,productList);


    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

   productList = dbHelper.getAllProducts();
   productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();     
   ...
}
```

Comment: can you post your ProductAdapter class?

Comment: recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); where this adapter come from. i think it should be recyclerView.setAdapter(productAdapter );

Comment: Use `productList.addAll(dbHelper.getAllProducts())`.

Comment: Why's that ? ...

Comment: hahaha . I did not see your answer i just made my comment. You are here only for 7 days you will learn how it works. Typing answer can took time depends on individuals typing speed, So that does not that some is copying the answer   And apart from that its not all about earning points for some people . Try to not make this type of comments in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the content of the adapter to product list and later you replace that variable by `dbHelper.getAllProducts()`

Solution 1: Use `productList.addAll(dbHelper.getAllProducts())`

Solution 2: Add a setter for the content to the adapter and use `adapter.setData(dbHelper.getAllProducts())` or add `adapter.setData(productList)` at the end